# MIDIThruConnectionCreate always creates persistent MIDI thru connection?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, coremidi

**Xcode 8 beta 2 / Swift 3:**

According to [Apple's CoreMIDI API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/1657995-midi_thru_connection), a MIDI thru connection can be established as persistent (stays in place forever, even after your app quits and your system reboots) or non-persistent/transitory (owned by your application and automatically destroys it on app quit).

The trouble I'm running into is that **I can't seem to create a non-persistent connection**, even though I am following Apple's guidelines.

It comes down to [this API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/1508523-midithruconnectioncreate):

```
func MIDIThruConnectionCreate(_ inPersistentOwnerID: CFString?, 
                        _ inConnectionParams: CFData, 
                        _ outConnection: UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIThruConnectionRef>) -> OSStatus
```

If you pass null (`nil`) to `inPersistentOwnerID` which is a Swift optional, the connection **should** be created as transitory. However, regardless of whether I pass nil or a String, connections are always created as persistent. (I can verify this by checking CoreMIDI's persistent thru connections.)

A summation of my code:

```
public class OTMIDIConnectedThru {
    var connectionRef = MIDIThruConnectionRef()

    init?(sourceEndpoints: [MIDIEndpointRef], destinationEndpoints: [MIDIEndpointRef], persistentOwnerID: String? = nil) {
        var params = MIDIThruConnectionParams()
        MIDIThruConnectionParamsInitialize(&params) // fill with defaults

        // (... snip: code to prepare parameters here ...)

        let paramsData = withUnsafePointer(&params) { p in
            NSData(bytes: p, length: MIDIThruConnectionParamsSize(&params))
        }

        result = MIDIThruConnectionCreate(persistentOwnerID, paramsData, &connectionRef)
        guard result == noErr else { return nil }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This couldn't possibly be a bug in the API?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and yes I think it always does create persistent connections. Probably an ID of NULL is the same as an empty string, because MIDIThruConnectionFind with an empty string returns all those persistent connections. So, a bug in the API or the docs!

I would recommend using a real persistentID, and remove all existing/stale connections when you initialize your MIDI stuff:

```
CFDataRef data;
MIDIThruConnectionFind(CFSTR("com.yourcompany.yourapp"), &data);
unsigned long n = CFDataGetLength(data) / sizeof(MIDIThruConnectionRef);
MIDIThruConnectionRef * con = (MIDIThruConnectionRef*)CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    MIDIThruConnectionDispose(*con);
    con++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've considered disposing of all thru connections with self-named `persistendID`s on app launch & quit but it's more of a work-around and obviously does not cover all corner cases, such as if your app were to crash it will leave orphaned thru connections which may not be desired. You said even in Objective-C you aren't able to create non-persistent thru connections? Then that would point to an API bug indeed or misleading documentation, and not a bug in the Swift API wrapper layer.

Comment: The idea above is to just cleanup any old connections of yours at app launch, before you create any new ones. I don't think orphaned thru connections will do any harm after the app crashes, unless of course they are made between external endpoints only. Then the "harm" will be that the endpoints are still connected. In an app I'm developing at the moment, I'm doing as I suggested above, which works fine because I only connect to or from my own virtual endpoints, so if app crashes those endpoints won't be alive anyway.

Comment: any idea how to do this in Swift3?   I can't figure how to create the pointer to the non-optional `Unmanaged<CFData>`  that Swift wants for the second parameter